# Looking for an equation that reflects the majority of a collection

Tags: average, sorting

I'm working on a computer program, part of which involves sifting through large collections of numbers (by large, I mean 16 million+ numbers). I expect these collections to almost entirely be composed of small values, but with a comparitively small amount of large values.

I'm after an equation that can provide me with a figure that reflects what the "baseline" of that collection is; more or less give me the average of the low-value portion of the collection, which as I say, ought to be the majority of it.

By way of example, say I have a number collection consisting of 33 1's, 33 2's, 33 3's and 1 10,002. This all totals to 10,200. The average of these 100 values is therefore 102. But the average for the 1's, 2's and 3's - the lower end values that make up 99% of the collection is only 2! I'm looking for an equation that can process a collection of values like this and (in the case of this specific example) produce a result of 2 or close to 2; to reflect what the "baseline" of the number collection is.

Answer (score 1):

Not an explicit answer but too long for a comment.

I doubt that there's an "equation" for what you want.

One possibility is to decide in advance on a threshold percentile - say 90%. Then just find the mean of the lowest 90% of the numbers. Experiment with sample data to adjust the threshold appropriately.

Comment: Just messing about, using the example I cite above:


Multiplying each value by the square of the number of times it occurs, then dividing it all by the square of the total amount of numbers in the collection (i.e. [(1 x 33 x 33) + (2 x 33 x 33) + (3 x 33 x 33) + (10,002 x 1 x 1)]/(100 x 100)) = rougly 1.65


Not perfect, but I get somewhat close to the target, by increasing the "counting weight" (if you know what I mean) of the more common values.

Comment: This weighs the more frequent values more, not the smaller values more - is that what you want? If our numbers are not integers you probably want to put them in small bins first. And you probably should divide by the sum of the squares of the weights - $33^2 + 33^2 + 33^2 + 1^2$ in this example.

Comment: Tried that. The result was 5-point-something. Well outside the range of my lower values. To address something else you said, the results I'll actually be working with will likely be similar, but non-identical non-integers. So the method I outlined above won't work for me in practice. But the theory might be a useful basis for something... Giving values in the "more common" zone heavier weight to effect the output of the equation... BTW, to answer your question, in my case the more frequent values and the smaller values ought to be one and the same.